# Changing HTML Font Size

Tags: html

At The Moment I am creating a website and at the moment the title looks like this

```
<h1><font face="tempus sans itc" color="White"><div style="text-align:center">Welcome To My Website. View My Projects Here</h1></div>
```

How to I make my font size bigger that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *style="font-size:required size"* property for this purpose.For example :

```
<h1 style="font-size:300%">This is a heading</h1>
```

For more info : [Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp)